# Angular 2: post job on jenkins

Tags: angular, jenkins, http-post

I am trying to "covert" this curl command into angular HTTP post, and I cannot figure how to send the --user

this command is used to start new job in jenkins:

curl -X POST 'http://10.1.11.160:8080/job/Job1/buildWithParameters?GW_IP=10.1.11.51&verbosity=aaa' --user angular:angular

I tried many things - I am unable to add additional header
I am using basic http from '@angular/http

this is my code without adding the header

```
runTest(){


 var Url = "http://10.1.11.160:8080/job/";
    var JobName = "job1" + "/";
    var Parameters = 'GW_IP=10.1.11.51&verbosity=high';
    var Action = "buildWithParameters?";
    var Job = Url + JobName + Action + Parameters ; 
    var Body = '';


    return this._http.post(Job, Body)
         .map(res => res.json());
}
```

this is what I am trying to accomplish:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post) correctly, you can still set headers using a `config` object as the third argument.

```
return this._http.post(Job, Body, {headers:{'Authorization': 'whatcurlshowedyou'}})
     .map(res => res.json());
```

You might also want to follow the style guide and name your locals using camelCase for readability.

Comment: I tried it already, it caused the POST to become OPTIONS in the pcap I record, and it did not add the header

Comment: You'll have to handle cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) since you're coming from a web browser and your app was probably not served to it by the Jenkins server. https://enable-cors.org/

Answer (score 0):

ok, I manage to solve this
here is the solution for helping other guys with this:

1. install CORS plugin for Jenkins
   https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Cors+Filter+Plugin
2. Configure the CORS support on jenkins

   - enable it
   - add: Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE, POST - or just OPTIONS, POST (I assume it will work)
   - add: Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Authorization
   - add: Access-Control-Allow-Origins - according what you need
   - I had also to restart jenkins
3. Here is the code I used:

   createAuthorizationHeader(headers: Headers){
       headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('angular:angular')); 
       headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
   }

   runTest(){
       var url = "http://10.1.11.160:8080/job/";
       var jobName = "job1" + "/";
       var parameters = 'GW_IP=10.1.11.51&verbosity=high';
       var action = "buildWithParameters?";
       var job = url + jobName + action + parameters ; 
       var body = '';

   let headers = new Headers();
      this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);

   `return this._http.post(job, body, {headers: headers})
        .map(res => res.json());`

   }